# CSS Transform to skew the shape to a trapezium

Tags: css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I want to be able to skew an element in the way the image displays below.

[image: rhombus]

I have been playing around with it, but dont seem to be able to get close to replicating that shape.

My css code is

```
transform:skew(30deg,30deg);
```

Is transform even the right way to do this? Please let me know the best, most browser compatible, solution.

Comment: Is it a filled in or outlined shape? Does the element have any content in it?

Comment: That won't be possible with 2d transforms... there are a couple of hacks using large border sizes to make shapes, but not reliable especially if you want content inside. Check out http://www.css3shapes.com/ if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, the element will have content in it, most likely a background image

Answer (score 33):

You can apply some rotate transform around the X axis and apply an appropriate `pespective` before:

```
div {    
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/300/200);
  border:2px solid red;    
  border-top-width:4px;
  border-bottom-width:1px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(40deg);    
  margin:100px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9344/)

Comment: I would also suggest using an X rotation, here is an excellent article that explains the rotations and perspective: http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html . I would use the rotateX, rotateY, and rotateZ as it is easier to play with as opposed to rotate3d or transform3d.

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy. This solution saved me from putting a lengthy js for creating the same effect. I used rotateX many a times, but just to put rotate animation only. You are really a saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Html

```
<div class="trapezium"></div>
```

### StyleSheet

```
.trapezium {
    border-bottom: 80px solid #fff;
    border-left: 45px solid transparent;
    border-right: 45px solid transparent;
    padding: 0 8px 0 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.trapezium:before {
    border-bottom: 90px solid #000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    padding: 0 8px 0 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -85px;
    left: -55px;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8BJUW/104/)</kbd>**

Comment: That's not actually a transformation; it just draws a trapezium. It's rather neat, though, and I can't figure out how it works...