# can i obtain this shape with css transform?

Tags: html, css, transform, css-shapes

imagine starting with a `500px` square `div`, i want to achieve this result:

[image]

i tried `transform: skew` but it looks like it skews the div only on one side, but i want to obtain this perspective look as if this `div` is coming right at you

here's a fiddle for some testing: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6oow6f/

any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Take a look here http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ scroll down to "trapezoid"

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177903/css-transform-to-skew-the-shape-to-a-trapezium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body{
    perspective: 50em;
}
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background:black;
    transform:rotateX(60deg);
    margin:100px auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6oow6f/2/

---

The `perspective` property should be on the parent of the `div`, which is `body` in this demo. The value `50em` can be adjusted as needed.

Note also that (unlike a previous answer), using this `transform` allows you to insert content that is also identically distorted. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kf6oow6f/3/

Comment: gillesc answer was more what i was looking for

Comment: "using this transform allows you to insert content that is also identically distorted." that was needed to :)

Answer (score 3):

Here, found on this good link for CSS shapes references: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e7m2gbqz/

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```