# Trapezoid on top of image and responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image like so:

[image]

I want to do the following:

I have a resposive html5 game, and i need a div on top of this image, in the same shape! of this image, and responsive...

Is it even possible with no pixels involved like in the example on this page?

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/
The shape is Trapezoid

Comment: That trapezoid on the linked page is a "border hack".  It works for visual purposes, but it's useless for most everything else.  What is the purpose of the overlay div?  Is it just a color overlay?  Will it contain content?  More details would help narrow down a solution.

Comment: It will contain content, it will contain a status bar on both sides, so if one side will have 50 percent colored blue and the other side colored red, it will have this all image behind a colored div in the same shape, so no one will notice the pic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Transform to skew the shape to a trapezium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177903/css-transform-to-skew-the-shape-to-a-trapezium)

Comment: Your best bet will be to use CSS `transforms` with `perspective` and `rotateX`.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23178068/854246.  Also notable is the comment below it with the link http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html

Comment: If SVG is an option, you could create a path with the same shape as the soccer field, and then clip the rest of elements with it.